# navigator getcurrentlocation calls forever

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, react-hooks

Why does this ReactJS code call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation infinitely? console.log in getCurrentLocation is called forever. Why is that?

```
    const [today, setTodaysWeather] = useState('');
    const [{lat, lng}, setLocation] = useState({lat: 0, lng: 0});

    if(!navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("gelolocation is not supported by your browser");
    }
    else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            setLocation({
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            });console.log(lat);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("Error getting location");
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lng + "&appid=")
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {
            setTodaysWeather(json);
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap this code in an effect, as that code is changing the state via `setLocation`, that triggers another render, which runs your code again recursively.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    if(!navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("gelolocation is not supported by your browser");
    }
    else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            setLocation({
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            });console.log(lat);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("Error getting location");
        });
    }

}, [])
```

The empty array as the second argument to effect function will make sure this code is ran only once, during first render of the component.